# Pander table in R

Tags: r, pander

I want to create a pander table in R out of a summary of my dataset. I always get four variables on one line, then another four and the last variable is all alone on the last line. Now I would like to have only three variables per row. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using and the output that you are getting?

Comment: Welcome. Please include a reproducible example of your problem - it'll make it much easier for people to help.